# Link kernels together

Tags: cuda, nvcc

I have a CUDA kernel in a .cu file and another CUDA kernel in another .cu file. I know that with dynamic parallelism I can call another CUDA kernel from a parent kernel but I'd like to know if there's any way to do this with a child kernel residing in another .cu file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

The key is to use separate compilation with device code linking, which is [available with nvcc](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#using-separate-compilation-in-cuda).  Since this is already required for usage of [dynamic parallelism](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#cuda-dynamic-parallelism), there's really nothing new here.

Here's a simple example:

ch_kernel.cu:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void ch_kernel(){

  printf("hello from child kernel\n");
}
```

main.cu:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern __global__ void ch_kernel();

__global__ void kernel(){

  ch_kernel<<<1,1>>>();
}

int main(){

  kernel<<<1,1>>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

compile with:

```
nvcc -arch=sm_35 -rdc=true -o test ch_kernel.cu main.cu -lcudadevrt
```

Comment: Thanks Robert! One more detail if I may: can I use a PTX file where the external device function is contained? Can an object file be generated by it?

Comment: It's not a trivial matter or a detail.  I suggest posing that as a new SO question if that is your interest.

Comment: Will do! Makes sense: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657004/cuda-linking-a-kernel-to-a-ptx-function